# How to Connect to Mosquitto MQTT server in VM using Typescript

Tags: mqtt, azure-virtual-machine, mosquitto, react-tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import mqtt, { MqttClient } from "mqtt";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const Subscribe = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // MQTT Topic to subscribe to
    const topic: string = "jobstatus";
    const mqttBrokerUrl = 'wss://myipaddress:8080/mqtt'; 
    // Connect options for MQTT client
    const options = {
        clientId: 'Testing',
        username: 'admin', 
        password: 'admin',
    };
    const client: MqttClient = mqtt.connect(mqttBrokerUrl, options);
    function handleMessage(topic: string, message: Buffer) {
      const messageString: string = message.toString();
      console.log(`Received message on topic "${topic}": ${messageString}`);
      updateUI(messageString);
    }

    client.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connected to MQTT broker");
      client.subscribe(topic, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Error subscribing to topic "${topic}": ${err}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Subscribed to topic "${topic}"`);
        }
      });
    });

    //To Handle incoming MQTT messages
    client.on("message", handleMessage);

    function updateUI(message: string) {
      console.log("Updating UI with message:", message);
    }

    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      client.unsubscribe(topic, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Error unsubscribing from topic "${topic}": ${err}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Unsubscribed from topic "${topic}"`);
        }
        client.end(); // Close MQTT connection
      });
    };
  }, []); 
  return (
    <div>
      <div>MQTT Messages...</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the component which I created to subscribe to a topic in MQTT and to show the message in front end. While running this I get **WebSocket connection to 'wss://20.198.14.124/mqtt** error when inspected.

I have tried altering my `mosquitto.conf` file as below.

```
listener 1883
listener 8080
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true
```

while changing the Mosquitto config and running, I get the error as:

```
1702358221: mosquitto version 1.6.9 starting
1702358221: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1702358221: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1702358221: Error: Cannot assign requested address
1702358231: mosquitto version 1.6.9 starting
1702358231: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1702358231: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8080.
1702358231: Error: Cannot assign requested address.
```

My Mosquitto server runs on an azure vm with ip-> **20.193.14.124**.

I need to subscribe to topic and display those messages in frontend. Could you all help me with this problem?

Comment: Mosquitto 1.6.9 is ancient. Whatever else you do you should run a much more recent version.

Comment: Forget your code for now and test the MQTT connection with something like [MQTTX](https://mqttx.app/). `wss://` indicates a secure websocket connection but there is no `cafile` (or equivalent) in your Mosquitto config. The errors in the log may indicate you have something else (perhaps another instance of Mosquitto) listening on these ports (depending on your OS try something like `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to see what ports are in use).

Comment: @AshwinRaj are u using Azure virtual machine running Windows/Linux